# Task Manager Script

Tags: windows-vista, taskmanager

I need to a script that will pull up the Task Manager in Vista but with processes from all users (like when you click "Show processes from all users").  I don't mind the UAC interruption but I'd like to save some time and go straight to the "all users" version.

I don't care what language per se, just something that'll run it native to Vista without loading any extras.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In the vista start menu search bar, type in "taskmgr" (without quotes).
- When the taskmgr.exe program comes up in the results, right click and select "create shortcut."
- On your desktop, right click your new shortcut and select "advanced" under the "shortcut" tab.
- Check "run as administrator."

Now, when you click on this UAC will come up. After you tell it to run, it will open up with all users :)

Comment: Hehe, my first attempt was to write a bat file. I named the bat file "taskmgr.bat" out of complete stupidity. It would not be a big issue if I had not added the "pause" command at the end for debugging. It took about four seconds to launch a few hundred command prompts... I had to reboot :P

Comment: DOH!! that's awesome..80)